# How to pass post data to php code using ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have written html as

```
        <input type="button" onclick="saveAndSend()">
```

and ajax code for sending request as

```
              function saveAndSend()
               {
                  var studentList = "1,2,3";
                  var employeeList = "";
                  var mailTitle = "Hello";
                  var broadcastMessage = "How are you";
                  var emailSent = "0";      

                    $.ajax({
                       url: 'index.php?action=saveAndSend',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: {studentList:studentList, employeeList:employeeList, mailTitle:mailTitle, broadcastMessage: broadcastMessage,emailSent: emailSent},
                       success: function () {
                         alert("hello");
                        }
                    });
               }
```

and php code for saving data

```
     public function saveAndSend()
     {
         // Send Logic

         // Save Logic
         $new_item = $this->apicaller->sendRequest(array(
            'controller' => 'Broadcast',
            'action' => 'save',
            'studentList' => $_POST['studentList'],
            'employeeList' => $_POST['employeeList'],
            'mailTitle' => $_POST['mailTitle'],
            'broadcastMessage' => $_POST['broadcastMessage'],
            'emailSent' => $_POST['emailSent']      
         ));

        echo $new_item; 
     }
```

I am trying to pass data to php code using ajax call, so that page is not refreshed and data is saved in mongo db database. The above code is not working. Please help !!!

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: There is no error in console but I think it does not pass data or run php code.

Comment: try by setting the contentType paramenters

Comment: contentType  is not mandatory

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to check that;

Comment: I don't have any idea about ajax... please help !!!

Comment: Put an echo inside function `saveAndSend()` and check if code execution is proper?

Comment: what do you mean with "not working"  ..have you error  (check for bowser  console)  ..  in several browser  there rae  tools for developer that chek for http send / receive request ..and you can inspect the result

Comment: A real developer checks the F12 developer tools

Comment: I suspect the API expects `studentList` and `employeeList` to be PHP arrays, not comma-separated strings.

Comment: What is the type of `$new_item`? Try using `var_dump($new_item)` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code it must help you.

```
<input type="button" onclick="saveAndSend()">
<script>
   // JS function  
    function saveAndSend()
    {
        var studentList = "1,2,3";
        var employeeList = "";
        var mailTitle = "Hello";
        var broadcastMessage = "How are you";
        var emailSent = "0";



        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?action=saveAndSend',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'studentList': studentList, 'employeeList': employeeList, 'mailTitle': mailTitle, 'broadcastMessage': broadcastMessage, 'emailSent': emailSent},
            success: function () {
                alert("hello");

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('sorry');
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<?php
if($_GET['action'] = 'saveAndSend'){
    saveAndSend();
}
// PHP Function
function saveAndSend() {
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nida You are adding TYPE=POST in ajax call and also sending index.php?action=saveAndsend that is query string url as GET type.